# Verify Certificate for subdomain without access to root domain

Tags: ssl-certificate, subdomain

We want to replace an expired certificate for a subdomain hosted in its own server, for example:

department.area.city.gov

We just have control over that server and subdomain. Because of security reasons (changed recently), there are no *@city.gov email accounts (usual way for verification, e.g.,webmaster@city.gov) and there is no way we can persuade them to add files or modify DNS settings in order to verify (COMODO alternatives).

How can this problem be solved? Anyone had experience with such cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some time, we managed to use Comodo and Geotrust --quick & cheap-- certificates. This is how:

1) Comodo seems to asks for *@city.gov email accounts in its common domain verification method. However, using its alternative methods, you can verify your subdomain adding a text file in it, like: http://department.area.city.gov/HASHFILE.txt

The trick is that the HASHFILE.txt **contains** another hash, it doesn't work if the HASHFILE.txt is empty -- which is different from Google verifications --. (that was my mistake)

2) GeoTrust certificates (like RapidSSL) can be validated using different level email addresses. This is: you can verify your subdomain if you can receive emails at: *@department.area.city.gov.

We went with Comodo, but Geotrust should work as well.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

Get another provider of certificates, one who will accept some other form of documentation proving that you have the authority to get a certificate for your domain.

The standard practice would be for an organization to have a few persons authorized to approve a certificate. Anybody can apply for a certificate, but it will not be issued until those designated persons have approved it. They need not have email addresses within the domain for which the certificate is issued; they just need to be able to prove that the company that owns the domain has authorized them to approve certificates.

Comment: I guess that will rule out any "cheap" certificate... do you know any that could do that for less than 50USD a year? (our budget is very reduced) -- thx btw --

Comment: The place where I work uses Verisign, but I believe they're significantly more expensive than that - presumably because they do have a very strict verification which requires human input and time, and therefore costs more. But at least you now have a case to put to your employer - they either need to fix at least one certificate admin address on the main site, or they need to pay a better CA to issue certificates.